# Messages from Camel XMPP not arriving in Pidgin via Openfire

Tags: java, xmpp, apache-camel, openfire

I have camel route sending to a producer template with the uri:

```
xmpp://user1@127.0.0.1:5225/user2@127.0.0.1?password=password
```

The server at `127.0.0.1:5225` is running openfire with the monitoring plugin installed. Both user1 and user2 are set on the server.

I have a pidgin client logged in on user2.

If I change the uri to send to a room and use the pidgin client to view that room, the messages appear as expected. However, as it is no messages are received. Using the monitoring plugin, it shows that the messages are archived in openfire with the participants as `user1@127.0.0.1` and `user1@127.0.0.1/Camel`.

Any ideas why Camel seems to not be sending to the participant I set?

**Updates:**

Messages sent from 'user1@127.0.0.1' to 'user2@127.0.0.1' and vice versa using pidgin clients works.
And running camel as 'user1@127.0.0.1' while logged in on Pidgin also as 'user1@127.0.0.1' means I receive the messages.

Comment: Does using the `participant` URL option instead of the participant URL component work? Are your user JIDs `user1@127.0.0.1` and `user2@127.0.0.1`?

Comment: no, I've tried that as well.. I've also tried creating the endpoint and explicitly setting the participant.
Yes those are the JIDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was sending using the following method:

```
producer.sendBodyAndHeaders(msg, exchange.getIn().getHeaders());
```

The exchange headers contained an `XMPPConstants.To` header which was overriding the participant field in the uri.